# C++ Idioms: How can an rvalue be passed around as rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, rvalue

The following code doesn't compile. Clang gives this error message: 
`candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'A' to 'A &&' for 1st argument`

this is as if `a` inside `f()` were an lvalue.

```
struct A{};

void g(A&& a){
    return;
}

void f(A&& a){
    g(a);
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

This is reasonable because prevent `f()` from calling `g()` more than once.

The following would fix my code:

```
g(std::move(a));
```

but looks wrong at me: think what happens if someone modifies the signature of `f()` to `void f(A& a)`.

Is there a better idiom?

Comment: Maybe you can use perfect forwarding, i.e. `template<typename T> void f(T&& a) { g(std::forward<T>(a));`  . plus some kind of sfinae to block types besides A. ... I don't think there is anything wrong with the original code though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but looks wrong at me: think what happens if someone modifies the signature of `f()` to `void f(A& a)`.

Changing a function signature with respect to the value category of an argument is a breaking change that might require manual checking of every invocation of that function. You won't find a C++ idiom that magically adapts to such a change.

The "fix" `g(std::move(a))` is the correct way of preserving the rvalueness of the function argument. Stick with it if `g` is supposed to operate on an rvalue. If you later decide that it doesn't make sense for `g` to accept an rvalue, but you want to pass an lvalue instead, refactor it - and adjust the invocations. In that particular case, the compiler will help you as it rejects binding an rvalue to the function argument `A& a`.

Comment: Then, if I've understood "Constructor(unique_ptr<A>&& uniquePtr) : mySharedPtr_(std::move(uniquePtr)) {}" is the right way to initialize a shared ptr data member with an input uniquePtr. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `std::shared_ptr`s can be constructed with an rvalue `std::unique_ptr` argument.

Comment: @jimifiki it's slightly better if you use copy-by-value for `uniquePtr` and no rvalue-reference. this way the caller can be sure that `std::move` actually moves the argument.